# react-select: Impossible to get value onBlur event

Tags: reactjs, input, event-handling, react-select, onblur

I have a problem with the **react-select lib** (see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select). For the validation of my form, I display an error message on the onBlur event. The problem is that no value appears in my logs.
However, onChange works fine.

**Handler**

```
const handleBlur = (e: FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element>) => {
//Here, When I select a value and deselect the input, no value exists in this log.
    console.log("value Select: ", e.target.value )
}
```

**The return of my component function**

```
<Select
            placeholder={`Select ${name}`}
            name={name}
            id={id}
            onBlur={(e) => {
                handleBlur(e)
            }}
            onChange={(e) => {
                setValueOnChange(e, name)
            }}
            options={options}
            styles={customStyle}
        />
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ];

  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const [focusValue, setFocusValue] = useState();

  const handleChange = (changeValue) => {
    setValue(changeValue);
  };

  const handleFocus = (event) => {
    const focusValue = event.target.value;
    console.log("Should be focus value", focusValue);
    setFocusValue(focusValue);
  };

  const handleBlur = (event) => {
    const blurValue = event.target.value;
    console.log("Should be blur value", blurValue);
    if (focusValue !== blurValue) {
      console.log("Do something");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Select onFocus & onBlur </h1>
      <Select
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Thibaud-S bro try this example, i hope you get you concerns.

Comment: That don't works, so, I used useRef() and it works. But that's bad luck, I wanted to use an e.target.value to process all my inputs the same way (classical input and custom select with react-select). Thanks anyway for your suggestion :)